# Sum Of MYSQL Values from Different Tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning PHP still as a beginner and my company has tasked me with creating a program to calculate daily sales by shift.

I have two tables:

```
attendance
id
date
time 
brand
branch
shift



attendanceout
id
date
time
brand
branch
sales
```

So when employees come in they put attendance in which goes to attendance table and when they go out their entry goes into attendanceout with the their sales of the day.

What I want is, data to come like this:

```
Date         Shift     Total Sales
10/02/2014   Morning   2000
10/02/2014   Closing   1000
11/02/2014   Morning   3000
11/02/2014   Closing   1500
```

I hope I have managed to explain it.

This is what I have currently:

```
SELECT a.date, 
SUM(IF(b.shift = 'Morning' AND b.date=a.date AND a.branch='DCC' AND a.brand='NISA', a.sales, 0)) AS 'Morning',
    CASE WHEN b.shift = 'Mid' AND b.date=a.date AND a.branch='DCC' AND a.brand='NISA' THEN sum(a.sales) ELSE 0 END AS Mid, 
    CASE WHEN b.shift = 'Closing' THEN sum(a.sales) ELSE 0 END AS Closing, 
    sum(a.sales) AS Total
FROM attendanceout a, attendance b
WHERE  a.date>='$fromdate' AND a.date<='$todate'
GROUP BY a.date
```

I also want to know how to display it in php.

Comment: can you give some sample data or a fiddle if possible ?

Comment: what are you doing with branch and brand?

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you have two values of 'shift', namely `Morning` and `Closing`.

It's not clear exactly how you join the two tables unambiguously. I'm guessing it's on `id` and `date`.  I suppose your `time` columns in the two tables don't match.

What happens if an employee works past midnight?

I think you can handle this more simply than you have shown.

```
SELECT a.date, b.shift, SUM(b.sales) as total_sales
  FROM attendance AS a
  JOIN attendanceout AS b ON a.id=b.id AND a.date=b.date
 WHERE a.branch = 'DCC'
   AND a.brand = 'NISA'
   AND a.date >= :startdate
   AND a.date <= :enddate
 GROUP BY a.date, b.shift DESC WITH ROLLUP
```

The `WITH ROLLUP` will give you a rollup row after each `date` and `shift` row with the whole day's sales.

You can then pivot each day's rows (morning, closing, rollup) to columns in your display program.

I used `ORDER BY ... shift DESC` as a hack, because we want the `Morning` shift to come before the `Closing` shift.

Here's the PHP part ...

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1', 'username', 'password');
$query = "paste it in from up there^";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(":startdate" => $start, ":enddate:" => $end));

$stmt->bindColumn(1, $date);
$stmt->bindColumn(2, $shift);
$stmt->bindColumn(3, $sales);

echo "<table>";
echo "<th><td>Date</td><td>Morning</td><td>Closing</td><td>Total</td></th>\n";

$olddate = "";
while ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {
  if (isset ($date)) {  /* skip NULL date (at end of rollup) */
    if ($olddate != $date) {
      /* new date, new row */
      if ($olddate != "") {
         /* if we had a previous date row, end it */
         echo "</tr>\n";
      }
      /* start a new row */
      echo "<tr><td>$date</td>";
      $olddate = $date;
    }
    /* write the sales value to the table */
    echo "<td>$sales</td>";
  }
  if ($olddate != "") {
    /* we had a previous date row, end it */
    echo "</tr>\n";
  }
}
echo "<table>\n";
```

This won't work correctly if a particular day is completely missing a particular shift; it assumes that each day in your SQL resultset is represented by three rows, one for each shift. But it should get you started.

Comment: How do I show the information as a table in php? Sorry I'm a noob :)

Comment: Getting Error: Incorrect usage of CUBE/ROLLUP and ORDER BY

Comment: Try `GROUP BY date, shift DESC WITH ROLLUP`, omit the `ORDER BY`.